# How to construct Nan in windows environment?

Tags: visual-studio, nan

I want to return Nan when item is not number.

```
double getValue(c_struct item)
{
    if (!c_struct_isnumber(item)) {
        return 0.0/0.0;  // in linux is ok, but failed in windows
    }

    return item->value;
}
```

in linux is ok; but when I compile it in visual studio, then get an error:`error C2124: divide or mod by zero`.
anyone could help me?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/nan-nanf-nanl?view=vs-2019

Comment: There's the standard macro `NAN`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/NAN

Comment: @NateEldredge compiling it with gcc in linux is ok. but still failed in visual studio.

Comment: It works for me.  Did you `#include <math.h>`?  What did you attempt to do with the value you returned?  Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: Also, is this C++ or C or some other language? Please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: @NateEldredgeThanks! above vs2013, it works. just failed when version is below vs2013.  C language.